# Bigquery failed to parse input string as TIMESTAMP

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, timestamp

I'm trying to load a csv from Google Cloud Storage into Bigquery using schema autodetect.

However I'm getting stumped by a parsing error on one of my columns. I'm perplexed why bigquery can't parse the field. In [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect), it should be able to parse fields that look like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS` (which is exactly what my BQInsertTimeUTC column is).

Here's my code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

project_id = "<my_project_id>"
table_name = "<my_table_name>"
gs_link = "gs://<my_bucket_id>/my_file.csv"

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gcs_creds)
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id, credentials=creds)
dataset_ref = bq_client.dataset(<my_dataset_id>)


# create job_config object
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True,
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    source_format="CSV",
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
)

# prepare the load_job
load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(
    gs_link,
    dataset_ref.table(table_name),
    job_config=job_config,
)

# execute the load_job
result = load_job.result()
```

Error Message:

```
Could not parse '2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155' as TIMESTAMP for field BQInsertTimeUTC (position 4) starting at location 64  with message 'Failed to parse input string "2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155"'
```

And here's the csv file that is living in GCS:

```
first_name, last_name, date, number_col, BQInsertTimeUTC, ModifiedBy
lisa, simpson, 1/2/2020T12:00:00, 2, 2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155, tim
bart, simpson, 1/2/2020T12:00:00, 3, 2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155, tim
maggie, simpson, 1/2/2020T12:00:00, 4, 2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155, tim
marge, simpson, 1/2/2020T12:00:00, 5, 2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155, tim
homer, simpson, 1/3/2020T12:00:00, 6, 2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155, tim
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loading CSV files to BigQuery assumes that all the timestamp fields are going to follow the same format. In your CSV file, since the first timestamp value is "1/2/2020T12:00:00" so it is going to consider the timestamp format that the CSV file uses is [M]M-[D]D-YYYYT[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.F]][time zone].

Therefore, it complains that the value "2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155" could not be parsed. If you change "2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155" to "7/7/2021T23:10:47.989155", it will work.

To fix this, you can either

1. Create a table with date column's type and BQInsertTimeUTC column's type as STRING. Load the CSV into it. And then expose a view which will have the expected TIMESTAMP column types for date and BQInsertTimeUTC, using SQL to transform the data from the base table.
2. Open the CSV file and transform either the "date" values or "BQInsertTimeUTC" values to make their formats consistent.

By the way, the CSV sample you pasted here has extra space after the delimiter ",".

Working version:

```
first_name,last_name,date,number_col,BQInsertTimeUTC,ModifiedBy
lisa,simpson,1/2/2020T12:00:00,7/7/2021T23:10:47.989155,tim
bart,simpson,1/2/2020T12:00:00,3,7/7/2021T23:10:47.989155,tim
maggie,simpson,1/2/2020T12:00:00,4,7/7/2021T23:10:47.989155,tim
marge,simpson,1/2/2020T12:00:00,5,7/7/2021T23:10:47.989155,tim
homer,simpson,1/3/2020T12:00:00,6,7/7/2021T23:10:47.989155,tim
```

Comment: Still a mess about it after passing '1/3/2020T12:00:00'. Maybe initial table setup matters, cause BQ shows '2022-10-18 00:01:00 UTC' in datetime column and doesn't want to accept anything except YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]. I've also tried '2022-10-18 00:01:00 UTC', but 'bq load...' cannot succeed. What's wrong?

Comment: @HelenKapatsa could you trim down your input file into just 1 row and try again? How many datetime/timestamp columns does it have? Also it will be nice if you could provide a sample row of data.

Comment: Adding a 'header=False' to to_csv() helped! Now '2022-10-30' is treated as a date) So bq load could not get through csv file with header, that's it

Answer (score 0):

As per the limitaions mentioned here,

When you load JSON or CSV data, values in `TIMESTAMP` columns must use a dash `-` separator for the date portion of the timestamp, and the date must be in the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD` (year-month-day). The `hh:mm:ss` (hour-minute-second) portion of the timestamp must use a colon `:` separator.

So can you try passing the `BQInsertTimeUTC` as `2021-07-07 23:10:47` without the milli seconds instead of `2021-07-07 23:10:47.989155`

If you want to still use different Date formats you can do the following:

1. Load the CSV file as-is to BigQuery (i.e. your schema should be modified to `BQInsertTimeUTC:STRING`)
2. Create a BigQuery view that transforms the shipped field from a string to a recognized date format.
3. Do a `PARSE_DATE` for the `BQInsertTimeUTC` and use that view for your analysis

Comment: Below the limitations you've quoted, there is a section where it gives some examples of dates BigQuery is able to autodetect. "For TIMESTAMP columns, BigQuery detects a wide array of timestamp formats, including, but not limited to":

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS
YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM

Notice how some of them don't use the dash separator and have the milliseconds. My column should be autodetected as timestamp (according to the documentation) but something is causing a failure.